# rails i18n locale specific config settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rails-i18n, i18n-gem

I am currently internationalizing a rails app and have all my translations in config/locales/.
I have my general environment config settings in config/application.yml, like API keys. I dont know where to put the locale specific config settings though? Like default locations and such?

Could I have a config file with different sections nested for each language and then only load the one relevant to my current locale?

something like

```
###/config/config.yml    

de:
  DEFAULT_LOCATION:
    location: Berlin
    country: Germany
    country_code: de
  HOST: http://www.germanwebsite.de
pt: 
  DEFAULT_LOCATION:
    location: Lisbon
    country: Portgual
    country_code: pt
  HOST: http://www.portuguesewebsite.pt
```

and then something like

```
#config/environment.rb or somewhere else? 
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/config.yml")['mylocale']
```

How can I get the "mylocale"?

I appreciate any hints and best practice advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put these in separate files in another directory and add the directory to the i18n load path.

e.g.

config/localized_config/pt

```
config:
  default_location:
    location: Lisbon
    ...
```

Then you can do `I18n.t('config.default_location.location')` and it should grab the right translation based on the current locale.

How to add to the i18n loadpath is covered here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#configure-the-i18n-module

This way you can re-use the built in functionality without having to put sensitive or non relevant translations in the main translation files.